# rails has_many and has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have two Models:

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comment
```

Comment:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
  has_one :user
end
```

What I want now is:
that each comment is related exactly to One User

But each user can have mandy Comments ...

But when I want to store it to db I got this error:

[image]

Where is my mistake?

Comment: you are defining relationship wrong way may be may be you must use belongs_to one of the model

Comment: and which one?, in comment database i've got the user_id column

Comment: in comment model put belongs_to

Comment: does it work? for you?

Comment: why is the question down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your code:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
  has_one :user
end
```

Try to change:

```
has_one :user
```

To:

```
belongs_to :user
```

And you can now use, `@comment.user = @user`.